# Background Image Stretch 100% Height of Div

Tags: html, css

I have a container that will grow/shrink in height based on how much text is dynamically placed inside it. The container will have a background image that needs to stretch/shrink as the container changes height and this image cannot be cropped in any way. I am wondering how would I style `.container` to get the background-image to be stay 100% of the div.

I have tried the following, but it didn't seem to work:

```
.container { background: url('backgroundImage.jpg') 0 100% no-repeat; }
```

Sample of HTML Structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">This is a short container</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">This<br> is<br> a<br> tall<br> container</p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to set the `background-size` property.
`background-size: 100% 100%;` will scale it to fill the container both horizontally and vertically.

I usually prefer `background-size: cover;` as it gracefully scales up the image as needed, maintaining the aspect ratio. Make sure to check the [support](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts) for background-size, as it is a fairly new property.

Comment: CSS3 is fine :) That did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 19):

In case `background-size: contain;` is not helpful and if you are looking for full HEIGHT background image without loosing aspect ratio then use below written CSS

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

setting first parameter to "**auto**" will ensure that image keep width in ratio of current height. Second parameter which is "**100%**" will help background image adapt same height as DIV.

Comment: I think this one should be the correct answer. It answer to the question and it works (browser support aside).

Comment: I personally believe that `background-size: cover` is correct answer. My answer can only help if @henrik's answer is not working. However, it should work in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try `background-size: cover;` ?

In your example you're adjusting `background-position`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a property in css3 called as background-size:cover; and background-size:contain;. You might want to use `background-size:cover;` to suit your needs.

**`contain`

> Specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as
>   possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to
>   the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

```
cover
```

> Specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as
>   possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater than or equal
>   to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

**